# Drupal - CCK - Node reference - Button for adding new nodes

Tags: drupal, cck

For example I have created the new node type with reference field in Drupal. I want to have aa button near the reference field for adding a new node of referenced type. And return to editing form after adding.
I have found this module - but it just adding a new empty node.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [References Dialog](http://drupal.org/project/references_dialog).

Only available in D7 however but it does eactly what you described.